# Create and use different tables in for-loops in R in a shorter way

Tags: r, for-loop, create-table, variable-names

I’m looking for a short solution to create and use different tables in for loops where the loop variable is part of the name.

I found the following solutions:

If I want to create tables in a loop I may use assign together with paste. E.g.:

```
for (f in files){
assign(paste0("A_",f), readWorksheetFromFile(paste0(f,".xlsx")))}
```

And if I want to use these tables I may use eval, parse and paste0 in the following way:

```
for(f in files){
  x <- eval(parse(text=paste0("A_",f)))}
```

The problem is that I have to use these constructions very often and the code is getting very long. Does anyone has a shorter solution to do this in R?

E.g. in SAS I could use something like (as I remember)

```
x = A_&f;
```

instead of

```
x <- eval(parse(text=paste0("A_",f)))
```

**Edit**

Based on the following answers I found this solution:

In the process of creating objects in a loop I may use the function

```
`%c%` = function(a, b) paste0(a, b)
```

in the following way for two or more strings:

```
"A_" %c% f 
"A_" %c% f %c% r
```

In case I want to use this object in a loop I can use the function:

```
`%u%` = function(a, b) eval(parse(text=paste0(a,b)))
```

in the following way for two or more strings:

```
"A_" %u% f
"A_" %c% f %u% r
```

Notice that I used the %u% only in the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a list:

```
l = vector("list", length(files))
names(l) = paste0("A_", files)
for(i in seq_along(files))
  l[[i]] = readWorksheetFromFile(paste0(files[i],".xlsx")))
```

If you need them to be separate variables, you could create your own environment and store them there:

```
myenv = new.env()
lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) assign(names(l)[i], l[[i]], pos = myenv))
```

And retrieve the variables using `get`:

```
vars = ls(pos = myenv)
get(vars[1], pos = myenv)
```

**EDIT**

So really you're just looking for an operator like `_&`:

```
`%&%` = function(a, b) get(paste0(a, "_", b))

"A" %&% f

A = "A"
A %&% f
```

Comment: Thanks. This might help in special situations. But it's not really shorter then my other solution.

Comment: That solution did not work in my case, but at least it was a great example. Based on your idea I created my final solution. See the edit of my original post. Thanks you helped me not just with this problem but to understand how to create functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I usually do when I have to read many files in a batch:

```
l <- lapply(paste0(files,".xlsx"), readWorksheetFromFile)
names(l) <- paste0("A_", files)
```

No `for` loop required.

`l` is a list containing named `data.frame`s. Use `str(l)` to exhibit the structure.

A single `data.frame` or *table* can be accessed in 3 different ways:

```
l[[1]]
l$A_File1
l[["A_File1"]]
```

## Dummy data

To make this a reproducible example I created dummy data as follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
readWorksheetFromFile <- function(f) {
  n <- sample.int(5, 1)
  data.frame(a = sample.int(9, n), b = sample(LETTERS, n), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
files <- paste0("File", 1:5)
```